# Rancher server UI unavailable (newie needing help)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher-2

First off, as the title says, in regards to Rancher I am a total newbie w/ very little understanding of the product. Second, if my issue has already resolved and posted on here elsewhere, please accept my apologies. I spent 4 hours on Google trying to find an answer w/ zero luck.

I have a Rancher environment that I "inherited" from an engineer who is no longer w/ the company and who didn't document anything concerning this environment. The environment has been running for over a year and as of last week I was able to access Rancher via the UI using Firefox. Today I went to login and when I go to the web page, I get "Secure Connection Failed".

I've done some preliminary troubleshooting (again, I'm a newbie to Rancher/Docker/K8) and there are several issues I've found but not sure if they are inter-related or how to dig deeper.

1. When restarting the rancher/rancher container, the mapped ports appear for about 90 seconds and then disappear and are no longer mapped. The container appears to be in a continuous restart loop.
2. When looking at the logs for the rancher container, there is a error about an expired certificate but I can't find anything on how to regenerate the cert outside of the Rancher UI.

Here is the error message from the rancher container logs:

```
starting tls server: Get https://localhost:6444/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Anybody have any ideas of where I can start to get answers on how to resolve this issue? This is a production environment and I need to get the UI working again so I can continue with my reverse engineering of the workloads, etc.

Comment: A good way to start is reading the errors, the certificate is expired, renew it.

Comment: Try to find cluster.yml file. There you will find more info about what is it. Maybe it is RKE or K3S or default k8s and you could start poking around from k8s side. Maybe even drop whole rancher altogether. Cluster configs are in etcd anyway.